# London Oyster Card - unusual requests

Tags: public-transport, tickets, london

Is it possible to request for the following? If the following are possible, what are the ways to request for the same (visit tube office / online request), and what would be the processing/admin fees?

1. Request a new future Travelcard start date, for an already loaded future Travelcard in my Oyster Card.
2. Request to convert Oyster Pay-as-you-go credit into a Travelcard.
3. Request to convert a future Travelcard into Oyster Pay-as-you-go credit.

Answer (score 4):

1. Maybe, it depends what you mean. Given that you can buy a week travel card as a paper card, and it doesn't have to be on an Oyster card, you can buy a travel card for any day in the future.  However if you've already paid for one in the future, and its on your Oyster, you can't fix that on a machine - you'll have to go to a staff member and speak nicely to them. In theory if the computer lets them it's possible, but it also potentially depends on who you get...
2. When you put PAYG credit on your Oyster, it's just PAYG credit. You cannot convert this to a travelcard.  However, what you could do is get a refund on that credit at an office, and then just use the refund to buy a travel card.  Seems silly, but that's probably the easiest way.
3. Again, like in step 1, for already purchased travel cards you'll have to speak nicely to a staff member and see what they can do, and whether or not they have the authority to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest contacting the Oyster Card helpline for those queries. They have better access to the Oystercard system than station staff. Plus they will have heard of many more strange enquires like this. The number is currently 0343 222 1234 : http://www.tfl.gov.uk/contact/4417.aspx#page-link-oyster-and-contactless-payment-enquiries